# Eclipse Oxygen 2 WAS 9 server not starting

Tags: eclipse, server, websphere

WebSphere 9 upgrade - Eclipse Oxygen 2 Server Not Starting

I recently encountered an issue when migration our Web Application from WAS 7 to WAS 9. Since the successful upgrade to WAS 9, our Server instance is not starting 
due to the errors below. Can anyone provide assistance in fixing this issue?

```
ORBRas        E com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport createServerSocket P=208274:O=0:CT ORBX0390E: Cannot create listener thread. Exception=[ java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind - received while attempting to open server socket on port 9100 ].
FfdcProvider  I   FFDC provider error
                                 java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE006 invalid StackMap/StackMapTable attribute; class=java/awt/Component, method=addNotify()V, pc=447
Exception Details:
  Location:
    java/awt/Component.addNotify()V @447: JBastore
  Reason:
    Invalid stackmap specification
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [28, 444] => handler: 447
    bci [447, 451] => handler: 447
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@23,Object[#916],Object[#923])
    same_frame(@41)
    append_frame(@70,long)
    same_frame(@76)
    same_frame(@96)
    same_frame(@102)
    same_frame(@122)
    same_frame(@128)
    same_frame(@148)
    same_frame(@154)
    same_frame(@174)
    same_frame(@180)
    chop_frame(@194,1)
    same_frame(@197)
    same_frame(@231)
    same_frame(@252)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@253,integer)
    append_frame(@257,integer,integer)
    chop_frame(@288,1)
    same_frame(@303)
    same_frame(@333)
    same_frame(@348)
    same_frame(@382)
    full_frame(@407,{Object[#918],Object[#916],Object[#923],integer},{Object[#382],Object[#382],Object[#918],integer,Object[#918],Object[#924],integer})
    full_frame(@408,{Object[#918],Object[#916],Object[#923],integer},{Object[#382],Object[#382],Object[#918],integer,Object[#918],Object[#924],integer,integer})
    chop_frame(@421,2)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@426,Object[#917])
    chop_frame(@433,1)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:867)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:136)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:703)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector.getDeclaredFields(Introspector.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector.formatTo(Introspector.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream$2.writeTo(IncidentStream.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector.formatTo(Introspector.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream$2.writeTo(IncidentStream.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.CapturedDataElements.formatTo(CapturedDataElements.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentLogger.writeIncidentTo(IncidentLogger.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.logIncident(FfdcProvider.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.logIncident(FfdcProvider.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:257)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentEntry.log(IncidentEntry.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.Ffdc.log(Ffdc.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.impl.Ffdc.log(Ffdc.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.startListening(WSTransport.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:838)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:605)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:157)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1362)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1697)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:555)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:698)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:422)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:179)

[07/03/19 17:20:08:602 GMT] 00000001 FfdcProvider  I   FFDC provider error
                                 java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE006 invalid StackMap/StackMapTable attribute; class=java/awt/Component, method=addNotify()V, pc=447
Exception Details:
  Location:
    java/awt/Component.addNotify()V @447: JBastore
  Reason:
    Invalid stackmap specification
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [28, 444] => handler: 447
    bci [447, 451] => handler: 447
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@23,Object[#916],Object[#923])
    same_frame(@41)
    append_frame(@70,long)
    same_frame(@76)
    same_frame(@96)
    same_frame(@102)
    same_frame(@122)
    same_frame(@128)
    same_frame(@148)
    same_frame(@154)
    same_frame(@174)
    same_frame(@180)
    chop_frame(@194,1)
    same_frame(@197)
    same_frame(@231)
    same_frame(@252)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@253,integer)
    append_frame(@257,integer,integer)
    chop_frame(@288,1)
    same_frame(@303)
    same_frame(@333)
    same_frame(@348)
    same_frame(@382)
    full_frame(@407,{Object[#918],Object[#916],Object[#923],integer},{Object[#382],Object[#382],Object[#918],integer,Object[#918],Object[#924],integer})
    full_frame(@408,{Object[#918],Object[#916],Object[#923],integer},{Object[#382],Object[#382],Object[#918],integer,Object[#918],Object[#924],integer,integer})
    chop_frame(@421,2)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@426,Object[#917])
    chop_frame(@433,1)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
    at java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNullHelper(VMAccess.java:55)
    at com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:867)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector$1.run(Introspector.java:136)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:703)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector.getDeclaredFields(Introspector.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector.formatTo(Introspector.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream$2.writeTo(IncidentStream.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.formatting.Introspector.formatTo(Introspector.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream$2.writeTo(IncidentStream.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentStream.write(IncidentStream.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.CapturedDataElements.formatTo(CapturedDataElements.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentLogger.writeIncidentTo(IncidentLogger.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.logIncident(FfdcProvider.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.logIncident(FfdcProvider.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:257)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.IncidentEntry.log(IncidentEntry.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.Ffdc.log(Ffdc.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.util.provider.FfdcProvider.log(FfdcProvider.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ffdc.impl.Ffdc.log(Ffdc.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:858)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:605)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:157)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1362)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1697)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:555)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:698)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:422)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:179)

[07/03/19 17:20:08:602 GMT] 00000001 WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:490)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:555)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:698)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:422)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:179)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:867)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:605)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:157)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1362)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1697)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:482)
    ... 34 more

SchedulerServ I   SCHD0040I: The Scheduler Service is stopping.
SchedulerServ I   SCHD0002I: The Scheduler Service has stopped.
AppProfileCom I   ACIN0009I: The application profiling service is stopping.
ActivitySessi I   WACS0049I: The ActivitySession service is stopping.
ObjectPoolSer I   OBPL0011I: The Object Pool service is stopping.
distSecurityC I   securityServiceStarted is false
CGBridgeServi I   CWRCB0103I: The core group bridge service has stopped.
DragDropDeplo I   CWLDD0004I: Stopping monitored directory application deployment service... 
DragDropDeplo I   CWLDD0005I: Monitored directory application deployment service is stopped. 
SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: java.lang.NullPointerException
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.deactivateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:1168)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.batch.endpointsensor.BatchSensorComponent.destroy(BatchSensorComponent.java:100)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.destroyComponent(ContainerHelper.java:341)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.destroyComponents(ContainerHelper.java:325)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.destroyComponents(ContainerImpl.java:607)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.destroy(ContainerImpl.java:598)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.destroy(ServerImpl.java:501)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:321)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:225)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:698)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:422)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:179)
SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.deactivateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:1141)
SystemErr     R     ... 36
```

Comment: you should use the backtick to place your error in a code block.

Comment: Formatting fixed, @AndyDangerGagne.

Comment: With transport stuff in the middle of the traceback makes me wonder if you have a port conflict, even though otherwise the errors aren't hinting at a port issue.

Comment: Actually, they are: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind - received while attempting to open server socket on port 9100`